# How can I make toggle(more/less) for specific span?

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code

```
$(".morelink").click(function(){
    $(".DescMore").show();
    $(".DescLess").hide();
});
```

But when i click one of the links, it shows all of them. I want to show only what I click. How can i do that?

Here's the html

```
<span class="Desc">
 <span class="DescLess" name="4" id="title">It has often and confidently been asserted, that man's origin can never be known: but igno...</span>
 <a class="morelink" onclick=""> More</a>
 <span class="DescMore" id="more">It has often and confidently been asserted, that man's origin can never be known: but ignorance more frequently begets confidence than does knowledge: it is those who know little, and not those who know much, who so positively assert that this or that problem will never be solved by science.\</span>
 <br>
</span>
```

Comment: you need to share your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide/show the sibling elements of the current element, so

```
$(".morelink").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this).hide();
    $this.siblings(".DescMore").show();
    $this.siblings(".DescLess").hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o5dmfvv1/)

Comment: It does not work for more link too right? i want to hide it too.

Comment: @real1 see the update... the `more` link is referenced by `this`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach. Toggling additional text and toggling the text from "more" to "less":
UPDATE -- I also added a fadeToggle to the text/

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zd0seke/2/)

```
$(".morelink").on('click',function(){
$(".DescMore").fadeToggle();    
if ($(this).text() === 'More') {
    $(this).text('Less');
} else {
    $(this).text('More');        
}    
});
```